# How to combine multivariate spline interpolation and regression in Python?

Tags: python, regression, spline, smoothing

**Goal**: My goal is to perform a regression on data where y = dependent variable (should remain constant) and X = independent variables x1...x4). I want to perform a regression of y on variables x1...x4. But before, I want to perform a (quadratic) spline transformation of the variables x1...x4 and then regress the spline-transformed variables on y.

**Input data:** My data is organized in  a dataframe as follows:

| y | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |

**Idea:**

1. Use *scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline* and perform a 1-D smoothing spline fit to the provided x1 to xn.
2. Extract the new x-values for the original y-values (i.e., x1_new...x4_new)
3. Regress new x-values x1_new...x4_new on original y-values (on a side note: with group LASSO approach).

**Problem:** I cannot retrieve the fitted x1...x4 values from UnivariateSpline. I also looked into *scipy.interpolate.griddata* and *scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates* but I could not figure a way out to manipulate these packages for my purpose.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated!

(+ Ideally, I want to be able to set a smoothing factor for the spline interpolation.)

**EDIT:** I think the required functionality should be similar to the package *earth* in R (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/earth/earth.pdf).

Comment: what do you mean by extract new x values? the transformed values for quadratic fit? your question or aim is not very clear

Comment: Thank you - yes, the transformed x values. I need to keep y constant for all data points entering the spline Interpolation since I need to regress the transformed x1...x4 on the original y. Thereby, I need to be able to know for each data point entering the spline interpolation The new position after the spline interpolation. Any idea on this is appreciated!